# Is it possible to force Quick Open to take a query from the current selection in the editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The current editor I have open contains the name of a file or part of the name of a file that I have in my workspace. I want to search for that file by selecting the text of that name from the editor, and then putting that text in the Quick Open search box. Currently, I need to manually copy and paste the text, but I want to have behaviour similar to the `cmd + F` search box where the selected text from the editor immediately appears in the search bar when it is opened. Is it possible to configure Quick Open to do this as well? Or maybe there is an extension for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, this is currently not configurable in a way that is nicely builtin to VS Code.

You can create a keyboard shortcut that emulates the behaviour like this (put in keybindings.json (open that file with `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette))):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
            "workbench.action.quickOpen",
            "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
        ],
    },
},
```

Note that since this workaround involves copying to the clipboard, it will clobber whatever you had in the clipboard before that, which you might not want (but unfortunately, I can't think of another workaround).

---

If you're happy with the workaround, then read no further. If you want something nicer, keep reading.

If you look in the settings, all the settings that allow enabling or disabling this behaviour contain the word "`seed`" in them: `search.seedOnFocus`, `search.seedWithNearestWord`, `editor.find.seedSearchStringFromSelection`. From my reading/searching, there is no other setting with the word "`seed`" in it.

I googled "`github vscode issues quickopen seed`" and found this GitHub feature-request on the VS Code GitHub repo: [Fuzzy quick open should use selected text as a starting point #59957](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/59957) asking for such behaviour to be the default behaviour. The issue didn't get enough support from other users to get added to their backlog (a feature request needs to get a certain number of thumbs up reactions from users within a certain time period after it is created to get considered for implementation), so that feature-request is now closed.

If you want to get such a configuration option, create a feature-request issue ticket. If you want to increase your feature-request's visibility (and therefore its chance of getting enough user support), share a link to it on various programming platforms such as r/vscode.

I didn't find any extensions that do this by googling "`vscode marketplace quick open seed`" and looking at the top results, but maybe you'll have better luck with different queries.

Answer (score 1):

Some history (and a request to upvote a GitHub issue).  What you want to do would be very easy if variables were resolved in the keybindings.  If that were the case you could simply do this:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+p",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
  "args": "${selectedText}",
  "when": "editorHasSelection"
},
```

But there are a few issues requesting variable resolution in the settings which are still open (e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809 open since 2016).

And recently, one issue was filed with exactly your use case:

> Similar to what we have in launch.json and tasks.json that we have
> access to these variables it would be nice if we can have it in the
> "args" param in keybindings.json for example i was trying to remap
> ctrl+p to pass in the selected text to the search but its currently
> not possible

From [Add variable support for keybindings.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196191).  That is one you might consider upvoting.

But an extension can do the variable resolution, so, for example, in an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), you can simply make this keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+p",               // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "description": "send selected text to the file quickOpen",

    "run": [            // run the vscode extension api
      "$${",
        "await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.quickOpen', '${selectedText}');",
      "}$$",
    ],
  },
  "when": "editorHasSelection"
},
```

and `${selectedText}` is correctly resolved.  Plus, the clipboard is not used to do this and remains unchanged.

[image: demo of using quickOpen with selected text]